# Living Force, Cosmic Force, Midi-chlorians?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Can anyone explain these aspects of the Force to me? From what I understand, the Cosmic Force creates life through the Midi-chlorians, but wasn't the Cosmic Force itself created by the Living Force, which is generated by life?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to quote from [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Force) for this, which refers to other works.

> The Living Force represented the energies of all lifeforms, and those energies were fed into the Cosmic Force which was responsible for binding the galaxy together and communicating the will of the Force through the midi-chlorians

Basically, the Living Force is every living thing.  The energy given off is then put into the Cosmic force, that according to Yoda "surrounds us and binds us."  It's will is then communicated through the midi-chlorians.

From how I understand it, you live in the living, feed the cosmic, and if you've got a lot of midichlorians, you hear what the Force wants and can make lightning and move rocks.

Comment: Doesn't the cosmic force also have to do with destiny/fate, sensing the future and so forth?

Comment: @Hypnosifl I'd go and say yes, as the Cosmic Force speaks its will through midichlorians, and thus all the fate stuff applies.

Comment: Out-of-universe, it's just extremely Bad Writing.